# Symfony Simple PHPUnit Exit Code 1, No Errors Shown

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony-3.4, simple-phpunit

I am running some PHPUnit tests on travis ci, and it is telling me that it is exiting with code 1... I have tried this on my local, and have confirmed that it is exiting with code 1.

The problem is, is it not showing any errors, no warnings, just deprecations.

Here is the output

```
PHPUnit 8.3.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing Project Test Suite
...............................................................  63 / 118 ( 53%)
.......................................................         118 / 118 (100%)

Time: 51.24 seconds, Memory: 58.50 MB

OK (118 tests, 444 assertions)

Remaining indirect deprecation notices (13)

  1x: The "DAMA\DoctrineTestBundle\PHPUnit\PHPUnitListener" class implements "PHPUnit\Framework\TestListener" that is deprecated Use the `TestHook` interfaces instead.
    1x in DebugClassLoader::loadClass from Symfony\Component\Debug

  1x: The "DAMA\DoctrineTestBundle\PHPUnit\PHPUnitListener" class uses "PHPUnit\Framework\TestListenerDefaultImplementation" that is deprecated The `TestListener` interface is deprecated.
    1x in DebugClassLoader::loadClass from Symfony\Component\Debug

  1x: Using the "predis" type for cache "metadata_cache_driver" is deprecated since DoctrineBundle 1.12 and will be dropped in 2.0. Please use the "service" or "pool" types exclusively.
    1x in ActivityLogRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository

  1x: Using the "provider" type for cache "result_cache_driver" is deprecated since DoctrineBundle 1.12 and will be dropped in 2.0. Please use the "service" or "pool" types exclusively.
    1x in ActivityLogRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository

  1x: Using the "provider" type for cache "query_cache_driver" is deprecated since DoctrineBundle 1.12 and will be dropped in 2.0. Please use the "service" or "pool" types exclusively.
    1x in ActivityLogRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository

  1x: The child node "cache_provider" at path "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default.query_cache_driver" is deprecated.
    1x in ActivityLogRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository

  1x: The child node "host" at path "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default.metadata_cache_driver" is deprecated.
    1x in ActivityLogRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository

  1x: The child node "port" at path "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default.metadata_cache_driver" is deprecated.
    1x in ActivityLogRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository

  1x: The child node "database" at path "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default.metadata_cache_driver" is deprecated.
    1x in ActivityLogRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository

  1x: The child node "cache_provider" at path "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default.result_cache_driver" is deprecated.
    1x in ActivityLogRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository

  1x: Using the element "deprecated" is deprecated for the service "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface" which is defined as an alias in "/var/www/Shred/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/dbal.xml". The XmlFileLoader will raise an exception in Symfony 4.0, instead of silently ignoring unsupported elements.
    1x in ActivityLogRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository

  1x: Using the element "deprecated" is deprecated for the service "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry" which is defined as an alias in "/var/www/Shred/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/dbal.xml". The XmlFileLoader will raise an exception in Symfony 4.0, instead of silently ignoring unsupported elements.
    1x in ActivityLogRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository

  1x: Using the element "deprecated" is deprecated for the service "Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager" which is defined as an alias in "/var/www/Shred/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/orm.xml". The XmlFileLoader will raise an exception in Symfony 4.0, instead of silently ignoring unsupported elements.
    1x in ActivityLogRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository

Other deprecation notices (118)

  118x: Creating Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UnderscoreNamingStrategy without making it number aware is deprecated and will be removed in Doctrine ORM 3.0.
    7x in PushLogRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    7x in UserAccountManagerTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Service
    7x in UserAccountMergerTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Service
    6x in GlobalFunctionsTest::tearDown from Tests\AppBundle\Util
    5x in ActivityLogRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    4x in ExerciseRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    3x in ExerciseTrackingRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    3x in FollowingRepositoryRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    2x in QuoteRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    2x in EventLogRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    2x in ActivityRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserSubscriptionRepositoryTest::it_should_return_the_latest_non_expired_subscription from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutPathRepositoryTest::it_should_only_get_workout_paths_that_match_the_type_and_are_greater_than_number from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserSubscriptionRepositoryTest::it_should_filter_if_canceled_flag_or_date_is_set from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserSubscriptionRepositoryTest::it_should_support_only_getting_the_product_id_and_date from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserSubscriptionRepositoryTest::it_should_support_getting_the_subscription_even_if_the_expires_date_has_passed from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserWeightTrackingLogRepositoryTest::it_provides_the_users_workout_times from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutBuddyConnectionRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_users_workout_team from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutBuddyConnectionRepositoryTest::it_should_return_null_if_the_user_is_not_part_of_a_team from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutMessageRepositoryTest::it_should_filter_by_coaching_type from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutMessageRepositoryTest::it_should_filter_by_random_status from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutMessageRepositoryTest::it_should_filter_by_a_specific_workout_number from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutMessageRepositoryTest::it_random_should_take_precedence_over_a_workout_number from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutPathRepositoryTest::it_should_omit_workout_paths_of_the_wrong_type_with_valid_number from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutPathRepositoryTest::it_should_omit_workout_paths_lower_than_the_given_number from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutRepositoryTest::it_should_respect_the_search_key_when_getting_workouts from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutPathRepositoryTest::it_should_only_find_paths_based_on_split_types_and_workout_types from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutRepositoryTest::it_should_find_the_active_workout_without_any_equipment from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in GlobalFunctionsTest::it_should_change_the_parameters_to_match_the_workout_if_passed_in_and_not_long_cardio_or_gym_levels from Tests\AppBundle\Util
    1x in GlobalFunctionsTest::it_should_return_a_shred_matching_the_passed_parameters from Tests\AppBundle\Util
    1x in TopPerformersBuilderTest::it_should_build_the_category_response from Tests\AppBundle\Service
    1x in WorkoutRepositoryTest::it_should_filter_based_off_of_the_workout_id from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutRepositoryTest::it_should_filter_on_recommended_if_not_body_weight_level from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutRepositoryTest::it_should_filter_on_equipment from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutRepositoryTest::it_should_filter_on_muscle_groups from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutRepositoryTest::it_should_return_zero_results_when_there_is_no_workouts from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutRepositoryTest::it_should_find_the_active_workouts_that_do_no_require_premium_equipment from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutRepositoryTest::it_should_find_the_active_workout_matching_intensity_and_level from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserRepositoryTest::it_should_find_users_for_the_global_view from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutRepositoryTest::it_should_respect_the_limit_and_offset from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_workouts from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in WorkoutRepositoryTest::it_should_filter_the_count_by_name_or_display_name from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_followers_of_a_user from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserRepositoryTest::it_should_track_progress_based_on_the_period from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserRepositoryTest::it_should_find_the_user_by_name_email_or_facebook_id from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_deleted_global_accoplishments from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_live_accomplishments from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_changed_accoplishments from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_v3_team_global_accomplishments from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_v3_global_accomplishments from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_team_global_accomplishments from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_deleted_team_accomplishments from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_global_accomplishments from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_users_last_progress from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_date_of_the_users_first_workout from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_count_of_deleted_or_non_deleted_progresses_by_workout_and_program from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in PopularActivityRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in MuscleGroupRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in GlobalTrackingRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in ExerciseForCircuitRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in ExerciseAlternatingRepositoryTest::setUp from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_live_grouped_accomplishments from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_users_first_progress from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_users_progress_by_the_addition_type from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserRepositoryTest::it_returns_deleted_users from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserRepositoryTest::it_should_get_matching_progess_within_last_half_hour_if_trigger_is_false from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserRepositoryTest::it_should_filter_progress_by_the_user from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserRepositoryTest::it_should_return_the_user_quantity_in_a_workout_team from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserRepositoryTest::it_returns_an_users_trial_and_access_info_if_it_exists from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserRepositoryTest::it_can_get_base_field_collection_for_multiple_users_and_filter_hidden_users from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserRepositoryTest::it_returns_an_users_base_field_collection_if_it_exists from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_date_of_the_users_oldest_workout from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_workout_shreds_quantity_for_a_user from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_all_workout_team_accomplishments from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_completed_workouts_without_long_cardio from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_completed_workouts from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_progress_by_workout from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_team_progress_for_the_week from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_the_users_week_progress_with_optional_modifier from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in UserProgressRepositoryTest::it_should_get_normal_workout_progress from Tests\AppBundle\Repository
    1x in GlobalFunctionsTest::it_should_change_the_intensity_and_level_if_a_workout_is_passed_and_the_level_is_a_gym_level from Tests\AppBundle\Util
```

Am I not seeing something here? 
How would I go about debugging why it is returning exit code 1?

Comment: There is not much to debug here. PHPUnit only returns 0 if there is absolutely nothing wrong (or you set it to ignore). This also is nothing to worry about, you have no actual errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is likely how you configured the PhpunitBridge's handling of deprecations. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html#making-tests-fail

> By default, any non-legacy-tagged or any non-@-silenced deprecation notices will make tests fail.

You can either fix those deprecations or set the `SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER` to a level that works for you.

Comment: Sure :face_with_rolling_eyes:, to disable the deprecation warnings will now solve the main problem that the code use some deprecations...